# MySQL: converting from bytes to float

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to convert a 4 bytes long array into a float, in the same fashion that python has `struct.pack` and `numpy.frombuffer`?

Comment: how are you storing the array ? what is the column type ? table schema ? mysql doesn't support array columns you know :) (but postgres does)

Comment: and I'm pretty sure there is [XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's an array of floats compressed into blob.

Comment: what's that column supposed to hold ? what's the table which has that column supposed to store ?

Comment: The column has type blob. The field has a number of bytes equal to 4 bytes* number of floats. I am trying to unpack that field in a mysql function.

Comment: You are saying that you know the underlying storage engine (e.g. InnoDB), know how this engine stores floats (in 4 bytes obviously) and have build a blob of multiple such 4 bytes? That must have been some work. Why did you do that?

Comment: You can open a new post to ask this irrelevant question.

Comment: @OriolAnd: Are you addressing me? I am just asking about your blob. Different systems store floats differently. You have a blob of four-byte floats you want unpacked by MySQL. MySQL uses different storage engines. So the question is: Is this actually the float format used by the engine? And if so, of course I'd like to know why you made the effort to investigate this and create such a blob.

Comment: I meant to ask what's the semantics for that column, for Example the column `username` is of `varchar` column type and it's supposed to hold the usernames of the website users in the `User` table, now what's your column supposed to mean ? and what's the table supposed to mean ?

Comment: I'm asking because I and @ThorstenKettner are almost sure you chose the wrong column type and wrong way to store data :)